Нужно NPM плагин правильно подключить к сборке Gulp
Нужно подключить плагин inline-css (который инлайнит стили), чтобы он работал с файлом index.html в корне проекта, и после изменения помещал бы измененную версию в отдельную папку.
На страничке плагина есть инфа про использование:
var inlineCss = require('inline-css');
var html = "<style>div{color:red;}</style><div/>";

inlineCss(html, options)
.then(function(html) { console.log(html); });

и еще доп. опции. Я не знаю, куда этот код вставлять (догадываюсь что в gulpfile.js, а как его создать? Просто вручную можно?), чтобы он работал при вызове определенной команды.
И помогите вместо примеров подставить в код правильные значения
